# Freeswitch India Progress tones

Tags: sip, telephony, freeswitch

I'm using **Freeswitch 1.6** to detect Progress tones. I need to configure India but I'm unable to find correct test numbers to validate Ringback/Busy/Reorder tones, looking for existing working settings.

Using **spandsp.conf.xml** module. I have US, MX, BR working just fine.

I looked into ITU-T standard and Asterisk sample configuration:

```
[in]
description = India
ringcadence = 400,200,400,2000
dial = 400*25
busy = 400/750,0/750
ring = 400*25/400,0/200,400*25/400,0/2000
congestion = 400/250,0/250
callwaiting = 400/200,0/100,400/200,0/7500
dialrecall = !350+440/100,!0/100,!350+440/100,!0/100,!350+440/100,!0/100,350+440
record = 1400/500,0/15000
info = !950/330,!1400/330,!1800/330,0/1000
stutter = !350+440/100,!0/100,!350+440/100,!0/100,!350+440/100,!0/100,!350+440/100,!0/100,!350+440/100,!0/100,!350+440/100,!0/100,400*25

India (Republic of) Acceptance tone - 400 1.0 on 4.0 off
Busy tone - 400 0.75 on 0.75 off
Congestion tone - 400 0.25 on 0.25 off
Dial tone - 400x25 continuous
Special dial tone - 400 2.8 on 0.2 off
Holding tone - 400 0.25 on 0.25 off 0.25 on 3.25 off
Intrusion tone - 400 0.15 on 4.85 off
Refusal tone - 400 0.25 on 0.25 off
Ringing tone - I (local calls) 400x25 0.4 on 0.2 off 0.4 on 2..0 off
Ringing tone - II (NSD/ISD calls) 400x25 1.0 on 2.0 off
Route tone - 400 0.1 on 0.9 off
Call waiting tone - 400 0.2 on 0.1 off 0.2 on 7.5 off
```

I configured **spandsp.conf.xml** as follows:

```
         <!-- India -->
         <descriptor name="91">
            <tone name="CED_TONE">
             <element freq1="2100" freq2="0" min="700" max="0"/>
            </tone>
            <tone name="RING_TONE">
             <element freq1="400" freq2="0" min="390" max="410"/>
             <element freq1="0" freq2="0" min="190" max="210"/>
             <element freq1="400" freq2="0" min="390" max="410"/>
             <element freq1="0" freq2="0" min="1900" max="2100"/>
            </tone>
            <tone name="REORDER_TONE">
             <element freq1="425" freq2="0" min="256" max="272"/>
             <element freq1="0" freq2="0" min="240" max="256"/>
             <element freq1="425" freq2="0" min="256" max="272"/>
             <element freq1="0" freq2="0" min="224" max="240"/>
            </tone>
            <tone name="BUSY_TONE">
             <element freq1="400" freq2="0" min="700" max="760"/>
             <element freq1="0" freq2="0" min="700" max="760"/>
             <element freq1="400" freq2="0" min="700" max="760"/>
             <element freq1="0" freq2="0" min="700" max="760"/>
            </tone>
         </descriptor>
```

I already have enabled debug level to 2 `<descriptors debug-level="2">`.

Comment: This appears to be a configuration question, not a programming question.