# Extract Progress tone from Audio file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, asterisk, sip, freeswitch

Is there a way to extract Progress tone frequency and duration from an audio file (Audacity, VLC, ffmpeg, etc.)

I need to configure Freeswitch **spandsp.conf.xml** for [India](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106951/freeswitch-india-progress-tones).

I collected the audio file where I can hear the tone, wondering if there is a tool to extract and configure the settings required in Freeswitch.

Current **non-working** config:

```
   <!-- India -->
     <descriptor name="91">
        <tone name="CED_TONE">
         <element freq1="2100" freq2="0" min="700" max="0"/>
        </tone>
        <tone name="RING_TONE">
     <element freq1="400" freq2="0" min="384" max="400"/>
         <element freq1="0" freq2="0" min="200" max="224"/>
         <element freq1="400" freq2="0" min="384" max="400"/>
         <element freq1="0" freq2="0" min="1968" max="1984"/>
    </tone>
        <tone name="REORDER_TONE">
         <element freq1="425" freq2="0" min="256" max="272"/>
         <element freq1="0" freq2="0" min="240" max="256"/>
         <element freq1="425" freq2="0" min="256" max="272"/>
         <element freq1="0" freq2="0" min="224" max="240"/>
    </tone>
        <tone name="BUSY_TONE">
         <element freq1="400" freq2="0" min="700" max="760"/>
         <element freq1="0" freq2="0" min="700" max="760"/>
         <element freq1="400" freq2="0" min="700" max="760"/>
         <element freq1="0" freq2="0" min="700" max="760"/> 
    </tone>
     </descriptor>
```

Image of progress tone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, audacity software have "Plot spectrum"

http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/plot_spectrum.html

After that use mouse hover on largest spike to see frequency.

Comment: Aren't Telco tones usually a combination of two tones?

Comment: That depend of tones and telco. You can easy search for list. If you have two frequencies, you will see TWO large spikes.